SQL on BigQuery and Google Analytics - Queries Merging
I'm trying to combine two queries in BigQuery to fetch data from Google Analytics.

Query 1: Give me the number of users on my website per URL & per day.
Query 2: Give me the count of events per URL & per day.

Ideally, the combined query would give me the number of users, total number of events and count of events per URL & per day. That would look like something like this:

Here are my initial queries.
Query 1:
SELECT
    date_timestamp,
    landing_page,
    total_users,

FROM (
    SELECT
        -- url
       (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'page_location') AS landing_page,
        -- date in YYYYMMDD
        FORMAT_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date)) AS date_timestamp,
        -- total users
        COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS total_users,

    FROM
        `company-warehouse.analytics_359623165.events_*`
    WHERE
        _table_suffix BETWEEN '20240101' AND '20240115'
        AND event_name = 'session_start'
    GROUP BY
        landing_page,
        date_timestamp
)
WHERE
    -- Filter by specific landing pages with partial matches
   (landing_page LIKE '%/blog/%' OR
    landing_page LIKE '%/features/%' OR
    landing_page LIKE '%/job-description%')
    AND NOT (landing_page LIKE '%app.company%')

ORDER BY 
    date_timestamp, total_users DESC;

Query 2:
SELECT
  DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)) AS date,
  event_params.value.string_value AS page,
  event_name,
  COUNT(*) AS event_count
FROM
  `company-warehouse.analytics_359623165.events_*`,
  UNNEST(event_params) AS event_params
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20240101' AND '20240115'
  AND event_name IN (
    'blog_website_click_signup_widgetcta',
    'hrgl_website_click_signup_bannercta',
    'hrgl_website_click_signup',
    'blog_website_click_signup',
  )
  AND key = 'page_location'
GROUP BY
  date;
  event_name,
  page
ORDER BY
  date;

Would appreciate any help on this. Thank you so much.
